# How to append a <div> tag into a <tr> tag with exactly position of <tr> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that contains some videos detail and I want to append a `div` element into a `tr` of this table with green color as a progress bar, with width changing from 0% to 100%, same as current runtime of video which that `tr` represent for. But in this example, I just set it static.
My code is below:

```js
$("#highlight").append('<div id="playingBar"></div>');
$("#playingBar").css("left", $("#highlight").position().left);
$("#playingBar").css("height", $("#highlight").height());
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
#playingBar {
  position: absolute;  
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.4);
    text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
    line-height: 30px; /* To center it vertically */
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="highlight">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>  
</table>

</body>
```

It ran well except that width of `div` element looks always bigger than the width of `tr` element.
Can everybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding `<div>`? You can give color to `#highlight`

Comment: you can append `div` only to `td`

Comment: You're generating an invalid HTML layout : `td td td div`, the div isn't supposed to be here.

Comment: @Sinto is right. why not simply give color to `#highlight`. It would be a simple and a better approach.

Comment: @Sinto: My table contains video detail, each `tr` represent for a video, I append a `div` as a progress layer, it runs from 0% of width to 100% while playing video, until the end of that video.

Comment: @ChienDang, Its ok, hope you got answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go with this and you don't need jquery if you want to highlight

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
#playingBar {
  position: absolute;  
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.4);
    text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
    line-height: 30px; /* To center it vertically */
    color: white;
}

tr#highlight {
background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="highlight">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>  
</table>

</body>
```

Okay because the #highlight is set to position absolute and you cannot set tr to position relative (it will look weird). The #highlight will get the 100% width of the body.
So what i did i just took the width of the #highlight into the var = width
and gave it to the #playingBar

```js
$(window).on("load resize",function(){
var width = $("#highlight").outerWidth();
$("#highlight").append('<div id="playingBar"></div>');
$("#playingBar").css("left", $("#highlight").position().left);
$("#playingBar").css("left", $("#highlight").position().left);
$("#playingBar").css("width", width);
$("#playingBar").css("height", $("#highlight").height());
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}


#playingBar {
  position: absolute; 
  left:0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.4);
  text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
  line-height: 30px; /* To center it vertically */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="highlight">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>  
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Your answer is right for highlight `tr`, I'm so sorry about my unclear explanation, I've just edited my question, please read and help me, thank you :)

Comment: Gimme a sec i will change it a bit

Comment: Is that what you want (the snippet on the bottom)? Or you need some animations as well?

Comment: I did animation bro, but the width of `div` looks always bigger than `tr`'s, I just need to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Traver, it'll better if that `div` still fill full of the `tr` when I resize table or browser. Now it was fixed with value `width` you've created. Do you have some ideas, bro?

Comment: at the moment it'S called on document ready just call it on resize aswell. 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#highlight { background-color: #feb5b5; }
</style>
```

Comment: This solution works, but the answer is poor. There is no explanation whatsoever (see @Traver's answer, much better quality)

Comment: Its simple, I do not think it need more explanation.

Comment: Yes, I know. Good work. I have also given him a vote. :-)

Comment: That's fair play.